# Does iOS 10 Safari support MSE (for MPEG-DASH)?

Tags: video, streaming

I am thinking about implementing adaptive video streaming using MPEG-DASH. I have read a lot of articles and found the information that iOS Safari doesn't support MSE, so MPEG-DASH playback is not possible. But all the stuff I have read is deprecated (2015-2016 years).

As of today, could you please point out if I still need to use HLS for iOS and MPEG-DASH for everything else or is there a solution which can cover all platforms?